# Light won't turn off

Tags: light-fixture

I had a remote ceiling fan that went bad. I replaced it with a plain light fixture.

I have five wires coming out of the ceiling: 2 white, 2 black and 1 red. I hooked up the wires to the new light (black to black white to white).

The light works but the switch won't switch it off. I next tried to hook the red to the other four black ones and the light still stays on.

What else can I do to make it switch off?

Comment: Can we assume that you didn't pay attention to what wires were connected to what prior to removing the old fixture?

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely have to do some testing to figure out what's what, since you didn't keep track while disconnecting the old fixture.  Start by opening up the switch box, and taking a look at what's going on in there.

Here are two possible wiring configurations, based on your description.

<sup>*These diagrams could be completely incorrect, so don't follow them blindly.*</sup>

[image]
[image]

Connecting wires simply based on color, is almost never a good idea. A multimeter, and some basic electrical knowledge will help you figure out what goes where. If you lack either of these two things, you might want to consider contacting a local licensed Electrician.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches:

Take the face plate off of the switch, if you are lucky you can see the colors of the wires and match the ones connected to the switch to the ones on the ceiling.

You could also use a multi-meter to find out which two wires are shorted together when the switch in on and confirm they are "open" when the switch is off.